# Converting a String into Date with specific format

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I've string in this form "29.07.2022" and I want to convert it to a Date

When I try this :

```
DateTime.ParseExact("29.07.2022", "dd.mm.yyyy", Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

it's returning the error: **String was not recognized as a valid DateTime**

What's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: you've asked 4 questions over a 2 year+ period and not accepted any answers

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I solve the issue. The problem was in the string with an extra white space at the end `29.07.2022`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).